# Accumulate observable array values into single final array

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

If I have 2 Observable arrays, `x$` and `y$`:

```
let x = new BehaviorSubject([1,2,3])
let y = new BehaviorSubject([4,5,6])
let x$ = x.asObservable();
let y$ = y.asObservable();
```

that I'd like to accumulate into a single array of values such that when subscribed to would emit `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It depends if you want to wait until they both complete or you want to accumulate values as they arrive. What you expect to happen when you call `x.next(7)`?

Comment: I would want them to accumulate as received.  I'd expect `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Comment: So sometimes you're going to push arrays like `x.next([1, 2, 3])` and sometimes individual values like `x.next(7)`?

Comment: I see now why this is troublesome.  I guess I would have access to the full array of values so I would expect `x.next([1,2,3,4])` and `y.next([4,5,6,7])` to emit `[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Observable.combineLatest( x, y )
.map( ( [ x, y ] ) => ( [ ...x, ...y ] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's this simple you can just use `scan()` to collect all values. It doesn't even matter what's the source so you can just merge the two Observables:

```
Observable.merge(x, y)
  .scan((acc, arr) => [...acc, ...arr], [])
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: your response would be correct if I was appending to the existing array, but since I'm providing the complete array, this results in duplication

Comment: so you didn't want to accumulate values as they arrive but rather concat the two most recent values from both Observables :).